# Correct way to show sharp images

Tags: c#, wpf, image, svg

I am trying change all icons to some kind of vector images for beter showing in higher size of "text, apps, and other items".

[image: Change size]

I tried svg image format, but it doesn't look sharp. (I tried many libraries, finest was sharpvector).

Sharp images:

[image: Sharp images]

Unsharp images when size is 250%:

[image]

Using svg converted to XAML with inkscape:

[image]

SVG Markup is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 15.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="16px" height="16px" viewBox="0 0 16 16" enable-background="new 0 0 16 16" xml:space="preserve">
<circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="7.9" cy="7.9" r="7.461"/>
<radialGradient id="SVGID_1_" cx="7.9004" cy="7.9004" r="7.4609" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0"/>
    <stop  offset="0.1198" style="stop-color:#DDEEFF;stop-opacity:0.1453"/>
    <stop  offset="0.4662" style="stop-color:#80C1FF;stop-opacity:0.5656"/>
    <stop  offset="0.7087" style="stop-color:#45A4FF;stop-opacity:0.8598"/>
    <stop  offset="0.8242" style="stop-color:#2E99FF"/>
</radialGradient>
<circle fill="url(#SVGID_1_)" cx="7.9" cy="7.9" r="7.461"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#B80613" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="7.984" y1="12.729" x2="7.984" y2="15.072"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#B80613" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="15.072" y1="8.016" x2="12.729" y2="8.016"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#B80613" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="3.272" y1="7.984" x2="0.928" y2="7.984"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#B80613" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="bevel" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="7.984" y1="0.928" x2="7.984" y2="3.272"/>
<ellipse fill="none" stroke="#1D1D1B" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="8" cy="8" rx="7.406" ry="7.484"/>
<line fill="#1D1D1B" stroke="#1D1D1B" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="4.133" y1="4.586" x2="7.813" y2="8.203"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#1D1D1B" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="10.914" y1="6.258" x2="7.984" y2="8.313"/>
</svg>
```

Even when I use Paths, it shows unsharp:

```
<Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:Name="HZS_pdf" Width="16" Height="16" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 16,0L 16,16L 0,16L 0,0">
    <Canvas x:Name="HZS_pdf_0" Width="16" Height="16" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0">
        <Path x:Name="Path" Width="14.9227" Height="14.9227" Canvas.Left="0.344" Canvas.Top="0.453335" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Data="F1 M 15.2667,7.91733C 15.2667,12.0373 11.928,15.376 7.808,15.376C 5.828,15.376 3.93333,14.5893 2.532,13.1933C 1.13067,11.792 0.344,9.896 0.344,7.91733C 0.344,3.79734 3.688,0.453335 7.808,0.453335C 11.928,0.453335 15.2667,3.79734 15.2667,7.91733 Z "/>
        <Path x:Name="Path_1" Width="14.9227" Height="14.9227" Canvas.Left="0.344" Canvas.Top="0.453335" Stretch="Fill" Data="F1 M 15.2667,7.91733C 15.2667,12.0373 11.928,15.376 7.808,15.376C 5.828,15.376 3.93333,14.5893 2.532,13.1933C 1.13067,11.792 0.344,9.896 0.344,7.91733C 0.344,3.79734 3.688,0.453335 7.808,0.453335C 11.928,0.453335 15.2667,3.79734 15.2667,7.91733 Z ">
            <Path.Fill>
                <RadialGradientBrush RadiusX="0.0294518" RadiusY="0.0294518" Center="0.500116,0.500116" GradientOrigin="0.500116,0.500116">
                    <RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF000000" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF252525" Offset="0.1198"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF909090" Offset="0.4662"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFDBDBDB" Offset="0.7087"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0.8242"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                    </RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                    <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <RotateTransform CenterX="0.500116" CenterY="0.500116" Angle="180"/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                </RadialGradientBrush>
            </Path.Fill>
        </Path>
        <Path x:Name="Line" Width="1.5" Height="3.844" Canvas.Left="7.14067" Canvas.Top="11.9953" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="1.5" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FFB80613" Data="F1 M 7.89067,12.7453L 7.89067,15.0893"/>
        <Path x:Name="Line_2" Width="3.844" Height="1.5" Canvas.Left="11.886" Canvas.Top="7.282" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="1.5" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FFB80613" Data="F1 M 14.98,8.032L 12.636,8.032"/>
        <Path x:Name="Line_3" Width="3.844" Height="1.5" Canvas.Left="0.0833334" Canvas.Top="7.25" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="1.5" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FFB80613" Data="F1 M 3.17733,8L 0.833334,8"/>
        <Path x:Name="Line_4" Width="1.5" Height="3.844" Canvas.Left="7.14067" Canvas.Top="0.192668" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="1.5" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FFB80613" Data="F1 M 7.89067,0.942668L 7.89067,3.28667"/>
        <Path x:Name="Path_5" Width="15.8133" Height="15.968" Canvas.Left="2.38419e-007" Canvas.Top="0.0320013" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF1D1D1B" Data="F1 M 15.3133,8.016C 15.3133,12.152 11.9947,15.5 7.90667,15.5C 3.81867,15.5 0.5,12.152 0.5,8.016C 0.5,3.88 3.81867,0.532001 7.90667,0.532001C 11.9947,0.532001 15.3133,3.88 15.3133,8.016 Z "/>
        <Path x:Name="Line_6" Width="5.176" Height="5.11467" Canvas.Left="3.5635" Canvas.Top="4.02067" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="1.5" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF1D1D1B" Data="F1 M 4.3135,4.77067L 7.9895,8.38534"/>
        <Path x:Name="Line_7" Width="4.428" Height="3.552" Canvas.Left="7.14067" Canvas.Top="5.526" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="1.5" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF1D1D1B" Data="F1 M 10.8187,6.276L 7.89067,8.328"/>
    </Canvas>
</Canvas>
```

Makes:

[image]

Similar:

```
<Canvas x:Name="Layer_1" Width="16" Height="16" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0">
    <Ellipse x:Name="Ellipse" Width="17" Height="17" Canvas.Left="-0.5" Canvas.Top="-0.500000" Stretch="Fill" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Fill="#FFFFFFFF"/>
</Canvas>
```

[image]

What is correct way to show sharp images in 250% size?

Comment: Even text is unsharp...

Comment: Try using geometry paths. Throw your vector image directly into VS Blender, and copy the paths and use them to build images.

Comment: What's the SVG markup here? If it's svg which just wraps a raster image, you'll find svg is not magic. Show us the svg markup of an icon and the code you're using to display them at 250% size and maybe we can help you. I.e. w'll need a [mcve] here.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your SVGs are not "pixel perfect", for example coordinates like `y1="12.729"` . WPF is really bad at deciding how to render non pixel perfect stuff smaller than the size it was initially created, while scaling up mostly is no problem.

Usually what I did was to open up [Microsoft Expression Design](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36180) and either adjusted the icon and make sure everything was starting and ending exactly on integer pixels or recreating them from scratch with inspiration from the original icon (which both are admittedly not the most satisfying solutions).

Also about the "unsharp" text stuff you can look into [this](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/control-concepts/text-rendering/).

Comment: Thakns, text is fine now. But I still cannt figure out what to do with images. Even when I use
<Canvas x:Name="Layer_1" Width="16" Height="16" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0">
    <Ellipse x:Name="Ellipse" Width="17" Height="17" Stretch="Fill" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Fill="#FFFFFFFF"/>
</Canvas>.

It is bad